# Incorporate or subsume?This is the main question

Tags: usage

In my office bio-data form I added three more points. I requested:

> "Please **incorporate** these points and make these points effective."

"Incorporate" or "subsume"? Which one is correct?This is the main question.

```
     As per New oxford advanced learners dictionary, Incorporate means to include something  that it forms a part of something examples [1} many of your suggestions have been incorporated.[2] the new car design incorporates all the latest safety features [3]we have incorporated all the latest safety features into the design.                                                                     
          And subsume means to include something in a particular group and not consider it separately example[1]all these different ideas can be subsumed under just two broad categories.
```

As per compact oxford dictionary and thesaurus Incorporate means include some thing as part of a whole [ synonyms- absorb,include,blend] But subsume means[usually passive] to include something in a particular group and not consider it separately.

But subsume means include or absorb something in something else.                                In subsume separate identity of  what is subsumed is not lost and can be  separately shown when required .

"please  include this,thanks"  is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use the word *subsume*. It's not a common word and it might even confuse whoever you're asking.

You could just use the word ***add***:

> "Please add these points to my bio. Thanks."

As for the part where you say, "Please make these points effective," I find that confusing. It's almost like you think that the wording is not very good and you're asking for the wording to be changed before the points get added. But it's hard to know for sure without knowing what software system you use to track performance data, and what technical terms people use when talking about submitting and revising the data.

Answer (score 0):

Return to the main question."incorporation" or "subsume" which one is correct? Subsume is-[verb] include or absorb something in something else and incorporate is[verb]include something as part of a whole. Logically both sentences have different meanings,however closer they may appear to be.If we we want use the both the words in similar sentences, where meanings are different. These will give distorted and misrepresented meanings.very careful reading of dictionary meanings , grammar books and thesaurus will help us arrive at a rational thought.This was answer to the main question.These points need not be elaborated with examples.I know I have corrected myself as well.